# "Cannot locate an element using By.xpath" error in selenium java

Tags: selenium, iframe, xpath, aem

I am getting `Cannot locate an element using By.xpath` error in Selenium using Java(IE11). I am working on a web page created using Adobe AEM(CQ5).

I have tried the following possible solutions but neither of it helped.

- Tried to add wait.
- Switch to active window.
- Tried even on Chrome.
- Bring focus on element.
- Currently using the absolute path (`/html/body/div[4]/header[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/nav/ul[1]/li[3]/a`) but also used relative path (`.//*[@id='cq-gen188']/nav/ul/li[3]/a`).
- Also searched whether there is any `iframe` involved. Unfortunately there was none.

To find the xpath, I have used FirePath plugin in Firefox. When i search for the element using the xpath in Firefox, i am successful. But when i execute the code i get the error.

Comment: Try to use `href` attribute of the link or identify an unique parent for the link and go from there. Please check manually the same selector in IE11 also to make sure is ok.

Comment: there's no original html. how we can help you?

Comment: the relative xpath won't work likely because is a one-time generated ID. You could also try By.linkText(...); or even By.className(...) if it applies

Comment: ID's are unique in AEM pages so why can't you use byId?

Comment: I think that the id which you have used is dynamically generated.So that value will be different when you open again.Please check that, if that is not dynamically generated.Check,If there any other element with this same id.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the correct IFRAME then you can use

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cq-gen188"));
```

Remember that ID is always [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) and that's a core assumption for all of the libraries in the authoring UI whether it is from core AEM framework or from custom components.

Your problem may be due to incorrect IFRAME as AEM neatly makes the UI look like a seamless window but there are IFRAME in place to facilitate various authoring navigation experiences.

Comment: i am able to search for the element through xpath on the browser. But when my script tries to search that element, it fails.